# How to format WriteLine from List

Tags: c#, list

How can add two numbers in a list that are related and later print them line by line?

```
private static ItemList = new list <int> ();

public void AddMethod(Itemarray) {
  foreach(var item in itemarray) {
    ItemList.add(id, stock)
    //e.g. 0,1
  }
}

public void print(list) {
  foreach(var item in ItemList) {
    //print two numbers here per line
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
0,1
1,2
3,4
```

Comment: try a `List<int[]>` (a list of integer arrays). or a `List<Tuple<int,int>>` might work as well.

Comment: When you post code here, please copy the exact code you're working with. For starters, your first line in not even valid C#.

Answer (score 0):

As Franz already suggested, you could use `Tuple` to do a couple of two objects (ints, in your case), and save this in a list

Then your print could look like this

```cs
public void print(List<Tuple<int, int>> list)
{
    foreach(Tuple<int, int> item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Item1 + "," + item.Item2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Franz mentioned Tuples, but they're a bit old school when used directly these days. C# now supports syntax like this:

```
        private static List<(int Id, int Stock)> ItemList = new List<(int, int)>();

        public void Add(int[] idAndStock)
        {
            ItemList.Add((idAndStock[0], idAndStock[1])); //id is 0, stock is 1
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            foreach (var item in ItemList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"id is {item.Id} and stock is {item.Stock}");
            }
        }
```

`(int Id, int Stock)` becomes a tuple with named elements, making for easier reference - you don't have to remember that Item1 is your Id, and Item2 is your Stock..

Plenty of tutorials out there about all the other things you can do with them..